# JSRender - how to render a sub-template conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I am trying to learn JSRender. Is it possible to render a sub template depending on a condition? Eg if #index = 1 or 2, render template A, if 3 or 4, render template B?

Comment: `{{if index == 1}} <!-- RENDER THIS --> {{>elseif index == }} {{/if}}`

Comment: Thanks, that's great. What is the syntax for calling the sub templates in this context?

Comment: what does sub template mean..post your code

Comment: The  mark up for each option is quite complex. Rather than place the code between the conditions I want to place it in sub templates and call them in the code. I've seen something like this...{{for article tmpl="#ArticleTemplate"/}}. Does this look right?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This code worked:
    
    <script id="testone" type="text/x-jsrender">
     Template 1 
    </script>
    <script id="testtwo" type="text/x-jsrender">
     Template 2 
    </script>

    <script id="tmplFeaturePanel" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for List}}
    {{if #index == 1}}
    {{include tmpl="#testone"/}}
     {{>elseif #index ==2 }}
     {{include tmpl="#testtwo"/}}
     {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
    </script>

Comment: Post your ans and mark it as correct

Comment: Note that {{>elseif ...}} is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax - and some documentation links below.

```
<script id="tmplFeaturePanel1" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for List}}
        {{if #index == 1 || #index == 2}}
            {{include tmpl="#test1or2"/}}
        {{else #index === 3 || #index === 4 }}
            {{include tmpl="#test3or4"/}}
        {{else}}
            {{include tmpl="#testOther"/}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

or an even more compact syntax which works just the same is:

```
<script id="tmplFeaturePanel2" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for List}}
        {{if #index == 1 || #index == 2 tmpl="#test1or2"}}
        {{else #index === 3 || #index === 4 tmpl="#test3or4"/}}
        {{else tmpl="#testOther"/}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

where in both cases the referenced templates might be:

```
<script id="test1or2" type="text/x-jsrender">
    1or2 {{:name}}
</script>

<script id="test3or4" type="text/x-jsrender">
    3or4 {{:name}}
</script>

<script id="testOther" type="text/x-jsrender">
    Other: {{:name}}
</script>
```

See

- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/composition/tmpl
- http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag
- http://www.jsviews.com/#includetag

*BTW note that `{{elseif ...}}` or `{{else if ...}}` is NOT the correct syntax.
In fact `{{else someExpression}}` works as an elseif. `{{else}}` works as an else.*

Comment: Thanks for a clear and helpful answer. This is an improvement on my code that I will be using.